# Dropbox Error 401

Tags: android, temboo

I was using Temboo for Dropbox integration for one of my android projects.

while the Choreos in the website runs fine and authenticate fine and my app compilation in Android Studio has no errors etc, I have a constant authorization problem when I try to upload a file using the standard example.

I have set the credentials etc as required.

```
08-31 21:06:28.348 31226-31328/in.ddas.pretense E/class in.ddas.pretense.DropboxTask: {"output":{"Response":""},"execution":{"lasterror":"A Step Error has occurred: \"A HTTP Error has occurred: The remote server responded with a status code of 401. Typically this indicates that an authorization error occurred while attempting to access the remote resource. The data returned from the remote server was: {\"error\": \"Unauthorized\"}.  The error occurred in the HTTPSend (Dropbox - Upload File) step.\".  The error occurred in the Stop (Raise error) step.","errortime":"1472670388137","endtime":"1472670388140","id":"56860062","starttime":"1472670387467","status":"ERROR"},"truncatedItems":[]}
```

This is the error I keep getting.
Where have I mistaken?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Temboo.

I recommend contacting [Temboo Support](http://temboo.com/support) so that we can get more info from you and figure this out for you as quickly as possible.